# Unable to get complete output of command module in Ansible

Tags: ansible, command, stdout

I need to store in variable & print the output of "ls -ltr" for a set of files on remote host. This variable with be used by another play in the same yml.

I tried the following however, it just prints the filename and not the complete results of "ls -ltr" command.

My lstest.yml looks like below:

```
 - name: Play 4- Configure nodes
         hosts: remotehost
         tasks:

           - name: "Collecting APP file information"
             command:  ls -ltr  /app/{{ vars[item.split('.')[1]] }}/{{ item | basename }}
             register: fdetails_APP
             when: Layer == 'APP'
             with_fileglob:
                - "{{ playbook_dir }}/tmpfiles/*"

            - debug: var=fdetails_APP.stdout_lines 

            - set_fact:   fdet_APP={{ fdetails_APP.stdout_lines }}
            - name: Printing fpath
              debug:
                   var: fdet_APP
```

Output:

> TASK [Collecting APP file information]
>   ************************************************************************************ changed: [localhost] =>
>   (item=/app/Ansible/playbook/tmpfiles/filename1.exe) changed:
>   [localhost] => (item=/app/Ansible/playbook/tmpfiles/33211.sql)
>   changed: [localhost] =>
>   (item=/app/Ansible/playbook/tmpfiles/file1.mrt) changed: [localhost]
>   => (item=/app/Ansible/playbook/tmpfiles/filename1.src)
>
> PLAY RECAP
>   ************************************************************************************************************************************************** localhost                  : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0
>   failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

Can you please suggest.

Note. In near future I would also like to add the checksum of the files stored in the same variable.

Answer (score 0):

As per fileglob documentation- "Matching is against local system files on the Ansible controller. To iterate a list of files on a remote node, use the find module." For remote host fileglob cannot be used.

Comment: This does not work even on localhost. fdetails_APP.request yields better results although not exactly inline with my requirement.